# Como puedo hacer para que despues de guardarlo como CSV me abra el archivo automaticamente

Tags: c++, qt

```
void MainWindow::on_btnExcell_clicked()
{
    QString done= "";
    tableView->setModel(mModel);
    QString path=QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(NULL,"Convertir a CSV","file","CSV(*.csv)");
    if(path.isEmpty())return;
    QFile file(path);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text)){
        return;
    }


    QTextStream Flux(&file);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(i<mModel->rowCount()){
        while(j<mModel->columnCount()){
            done+= tableView->model()->index(i,j).data().toString();
            if(j!=mModel->columnCount()){
                done+= ";";
            }
            j++;
        }
        done+= "\n";
        j=0;
        i++;
    }

    Flux << done;

    file.close();

    /* csv=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"abrir archivo",QDir::rootPath(),"*csv");
    QFile archivo(csv);
    if(!archivo.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error",archivo.errorString());
        return;
    }
    archivo.readAll();*/
}
```

este codigo convierte una tabla en csv una vez creado el archivo.csv lo que quiero es que a continuación se me habra el archivo creado

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Qué es el código que has pegado? ¿Qué se supone que debe hacer? ¿Qué datos recibe? ¿Qué datos esperas que devuelva?

Answer (score 0):

Con esto arreglé lo que buscaba:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path));
```